# Find index of all true inside massive

Tags: swift

I've an array of booleans there are 10 trues and falses and I want to know the index of all trues

```swift
var trueAndFalses = [false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false]
```

I tried `firstIndex` but it only returns the firstIndex ( yes kinda ironic ). now I wonder is there any built in functions to find all the indexes of `true`

```swift
print(trueAndFalses.firstIndex(of: true))
```

any solution will be appericated <3

Comment: You can use `filter` to get all the `true`. Can you explain what are you trying to do with index?

Comment: `trueAndFalses.indices.filter { trueAndFalses[$0] == true }` (with explicit `== true`)?

Comment: @Larme: `trueAndFalses.indices.filter { trueAndFalses[$0] }` is sufficient.

Comment: @MartinR Indeed, I wrote "with explicit == true", meaning that it was optional writing. Because I'm wondering if it's not a "simplified" example, so just `trueAndFalse[$0]` in the closure might have been harder to understand... That's just why I explicitly wrote it...

Comment: @Larme: Then I misunderstood your remark! (I would always omit a redundant `== true`, but that may be a personal preference.)

Comment: Larme, you should post your comment as an answer. (And I would reword your "with explicit ==" to say something like: "the '== true' part is not needed. I added it to make it clear what the filter function is checking.")

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find all index by visiting all elements and checking if its true like below:

```
var trueAndFalses = [false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false]
for var i in (0..<trueAndFalses.count){
    if (trueAndFalses[i] == true)
    {
        print("true fount at index ",i)
    }
}
Output:
true fount at index  2
true fount at index  6

Other way:
let indices = trueAndFalses.enumerated().compactMap { $1 == true ? $0 : nil }
print(indices)

Output:
[2, 6]
```